# Installer for Java Database Application

Tags: java, deployment, installation

I have created a Java Maven Build Hibernate 2.0 Application with Eclipse.

I want to create .exe Installer for this project. Is there any way that I can make .exe app. and then use this .exe to run this .exe project.
Did I need to fix Database? like hibernate stuff? or any other issue, please also give me your expert opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is unnecessary to make .exe from your project. However for convenience you can use a so called "launcher" to invoke the JVM for you.

Two examples:

- http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.ucware.com/jexec/index.htm

Most Java programs can be designed not to need an installer. See Tomcat, Glassfish, Eclipse for example. If you need specific installation process, maybe you should consider writing an Ant script (this is an xml file that can be run with a tool, very easy to write install processed in it.)

The database setup can be the only tricky step, but maybe a simple configuration file containing the JDBC url and login data can be enough.

Comment: in the case of Hibernate(hibernate.xml file), contains all the necessary information of database url and dbname,password and other database dialect information in it. In may project this file is also a part of my Project Structure. But I don't know in the case when .exe file will be created, this hibernate.xml file will also be included in it, or does database be configured for this project application additionally.??...

Comment: I thing you misunderstand the very basic concept of Java and the JVM stuff. There is no native (exe) code in the picture! The JVM is the exe, to oversimlify things. Your compiled program is the "input" of the JVM program.